# Delete all data of a specific section

Tags: symphony-cms

I need to delete all the data in a specific section. Because I have several hundreds, I cannot manually delete them.

Also, I cannot delete the section and rebuilt because the section is tied to a third party sync tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Symphony 2.3.3 :

1. Go to Blueprint -> Sections
2. Select the section that has your entries (highlight the row)
3. From the 'with selected...' drop down, selct 'delete entries'
4. Click on apply

This should delete all your entries for that section.